# Fast Compare an NSString with contents of JSON

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, nsstring, compare

In an iOS app, I have a large JSON file. The file has only one key 'words' that has ~100,000 words in array format.

In my app I generate multiple strings. I want to iterate through the JSON, which I currently have saved to an array of strings, and compare each value from that array with my generated string. I need to know if my generated string contains any of the JSON strings.

Example:

Generated String: "My name is Bill"

I need to iterate over the JSON or the array and compare each value with that generated string to see if any of the JSON strings are in the generated string.

I need this to happen very quickly and efficiently.

I currently use:

```
for (NSString*s in jsonArray){
    if ([generatedString rangeOfString:[s uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
        // do things
    }
}
```

This works, but is very slow as I have 20 generated strings that each need to be searched for any of the JSON stings. This gets repeated numerous times as each of the generated strings change.

What is my best option? Should I use CoreData or SQLite instead? If so (I'm not super familiar with either) how would the comparisons be made, using the same 'rangeOfString' method I use now? Don't both of those require me to pull all the data into an array first for this kind of comparison?

I can use another file format other than JSON if need be. (It is basically just a list of 100,000 words).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the compare on word boundaries of the generated string?

Comment: I think you may want to think about this from different point of view, have a read at this http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Once you parse the JSON into an array you're no longer dealing with JSON, you're dealing with an array.  If you check the spec for NSArray there are several techniques for searching one.  `indexOfObjectPassingTest`, eg, would presumably be somewhat more efficient.  But it would probably be more efficient to put your word list into an NSSet.

Comment: If possible use an `NSOrderedSet` with `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`. The key is what your criteria are for the generated string.